# Separar columnas de un dataframe por cantidad de caracteres en python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

me baje una base de dato txt. en donde creeria que la mejor forma de separarlos serias por cantidad de caracteres ya que algunos datos vienen separados por un espacio, otros por tabulaciones y otros todo junto.... adjunto la imagen y espero que ppuedan ayudarme a encontrar la mejor manera de separa estos datos en columnas 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Efectivamente, pareciera tratarse de un "Fixed record lenght format", cada columna tiene una longitud fija. Pandas  tiene un función para leer estos archivos: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html. Te sugiero que compartas el código de lo que hayas intentado para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias sos un crack!! perdon estoy empezando en esto de ML .. que seria el codigo exactamente?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar

```
pd.read_fwf('archivo')
```

Esto te cargará el archivo en un dataframe y luego puedes manejarlo con pandas.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, te falta la parte más importante, que es indicar como se definen las las posiciones de cada columna.